# How to get text from dropped <li>?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I have drag&drop jQuery script for dragging list items to input. How do I get text between `li` to set input value? I now that `$this` refers to droppable element.

My code is below:

```
    <script type"text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $( ".draggable" ).draggable({
                revert: "valid"
            });
            $( ".droppable" ).droppable({
                drop: function( event, ui ) {
                $( this )
                    .find( "input" )
                    .val( "?" )
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="left">
    <ul>
        <li class="draggable">one</li>
        <li class="draggable">two</li>
        <li class="draggable">three</li>
        <li class="draggable">four</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="right">
    <form>
        <div class="droppable">First <input class="droppable" type="text" name="first" value="" /></div>
        <div class="droppable">Second <input class="droppable" type="text" name="second" value="" /></div>
        <div class="droppable">Third <input class="droppable" type="text" name="third" value="" /></div>
        <div class="droppable">Fourth <input class="droppable" type="text" name="fourth" value="" /></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
function( event, ui ) {
           $( this )
               .find( "input" )
               .val( $(ui.draggable).text() )
           }
}
```

The `ui.draggable` param is the draggable element that have been dropped.

[Quoting Jquery-UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/):

> All callbacks receive two arguments: The original browser event and a
>   prepared ui object, view below for a documentation of this object (if
>   you name your second argument 'ui'):
>
> **ui.draggable** - current draggable element, a jQuery object. **ui.helper** -
>   current draggable helper, a jQuery object **ui.position** - current
>   position of the draggable helper { top: , left: } **ui.offset** - current
>   absolute position of the draggable helper { top: , left: }

Comment: @stamp: True. Use _text()_ instead of _val()_. I'll update the answer

Answer (score 2):

`ui.draggable` - current draggable element, a jQuery object.